What does "take in" mean in "There was a neighbor who was a rancher who was going to **take me in** at eleven o'clock"?
This context comes from the book "Outliers" by Malcolm Gladwell. This part of the book talks about a man whose car broke down and was unable to attend his college lectures so he decided to come to talk about this issue to his adviser and his dean.
"The transmission fell out of my car, and you have me in a seven-thirty a.m. and eight-thirty a.m. class. If you could please just transfer me to the afternoon sections of these classes, I would appreciate it because of this car problem. There was a neighbor who was a rancher who was going to take me in at eleven o'clock."
I can't find a phrasal verb take in that would fit the context. I've heard of "taking someone into town" by giving them a ride but this one is new to me. Does it mean the same thing? In this case "in" would be a preposition meaning:
a. Within the limits, bounds, or area of: was hit in the face; born in the spring; a chair in the garden.(American Heritage Dictionary)

Why not the exact same meaning as your example: "take me into college"?

In my country that would suggest that you are going to park inside the building.

Really? Even if the college was on a campus with multiple buildings? If someone said they were going to drive you to the shops would you expect them to drive into a shop?

"To the shops" would be the correct form in my country. "into" or "in" would suggest something else.

If my son's car is not working and I have some time spare, I could take him in, and that does not mean that I drive the car into his office building, or that I carry him from the car all the way to her desk. I could take him in or he could take me in to the town centre also. To conduct someone somewhere. 'The manager is ready to see you, so I'll take you in', said her assistant.

Re "To the shops" would be the correct form in my country... Note that to go in and to go out aren't normally "phrasal verbs". Also note that besides We went in the shop and She went out the door, we can say I went to the shop. But whereas the object isn't syntactically necessary for the first 2 (We went in, She went out), it's simply not possible in English to say I went to.

@StaticBounce Sometimes giving little text is confusing. It appeared (to me and others) that he was informing the Dean about his rancher neighbour. But when I read the full text online it was clear. These are two separate sentences; [ I would appreciate it because of this car problem.] {There was a neighbor who was a rancher who was going to take me in at eleven o'clock."}.

Here, take in doesn’t look like a phrasal verb—as it would be, for instance, if one were talking about reducing some measurement of a garment: My blazer fits me perfectly now that the tailor has taken in the shoulders.
Instead, it seems to have the literal sense of its parts, take and in, thus meaning “transport in [to town, where the school is presumably located].”
But, as usual, one cannot be certain without additional context.

Is "take in" simply a shorter form of "take into" and in thus form, simply because the destination at the end is omitted? Could he also say, following the same rationale **"...who was going to take me to""*?

No, he couldn't. The meaning of some words of this type can be understood from the context (if a person in a boat or by a waterside 'falls in', the rider of a horse or bike 'falls off'), but it doesn't work with to.

It seems to mean "drive me in (from where I live[d] to campus)".  But the past tense is odd in context.  Have you given the full context? Or is that man telling someone about the story he told to his dean back when he was in college?

There was a neighbor who was a rancher who was going to take me in at eleven o'clock.

Those words make no sense as words spoken to the dean at the time.
P.S. Since the person who volunteered to "take him in" was a rancher at the time, presumably he lives out in a rural area on a ranch.  It is very common to speak of going in to the city when one lives outside of it, in the suburbs and especially if one lives in a rural area.

I'll take you in.

The preposition to introduces a destination and requires an object (e.g. to your campus, to your class, to the school) whereas "take you in" does not.  Similarly, if someone at school volunteered to drive him home, the offer might have been made in the form "I'll take you out" or "I can take you back out".

No, the sentence you cited is spoken to the author of the book during his research. The man whose car broke down talks to him about the incident. Sorry, I failed to realize that when writing this post.

OP asked about the meaning of the phrase  "take me in" from Malcolm Gladwell's Outliers: The Story of Success (2008):

There was a neighbor who was a rancher who was going to take me in at eleven o'clock.

The speaker,  Christopher Michael Langan, an American horse rancher and former bar bouncer known for his exceptionally high IQ, is recalling an incident (30 years ago) that led him to stop his education. He was unable to attend early morning college classes due to transportation issues. His requests to switch to afternoon classes were denied by both his advisor and the Dean.
In this context,  "take me in" likely means  to give a ride (to college), (similar to  "take someone into town,") with "in" functioning as a preposition of direction or movement.
The mention of his neighbor being a rancher indicates they lived far from campus (rural setting). The phrase implies that the neighbor offered to drive him (daily at 11 AM to college, or perhaps transportation by horseback  given the rural context.)

The speaker' is   Christopher Michael Langan, an American horse rancher and former bar bouncer, who was listed in the Guinness Book of Records high IQ section. The author Malcolm Gladwell's   sought to understand why Langan's high IQ had not led to greater success in life.


There is an important clue in your excerpt: at 11 a.m. (appointment)


There is another important clue in your excerpt: neighbor (close)


There is still another important clue in your excerpt: "afternoon sections" (morning sections are impossible because neighbor comes at 11 a.m.)


There is also an important meaning in take in : to go to; visit
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-in

visit or attend a place or event in a casual way or on the way to another
https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/4173d5569ba841819fc78a9b762bd08d


From these contexts there is one conclusion.
The neighbor will visit you at 11 a.m. on his way to another(maybe very close to the college).

There is a similar expression for a short visit: look in on, drop in on, call on

Note that if you change morning sections to afternoon ones, it's maybe not just a one-off.

The "attend an event" definition of "take in" (as in "we decided to take in a Broadway show") is not relevant to this excerpt. Your conclusion that the neighbor intends to visit the speaker is incorrect. The neighbor is going to transport the speaker to college at 11 am.

What about Collins definition: to go to or visit? If you transport someone to somewhere, you must visit someone. I think as the dictionary defines 'take in' includes the meaning of 'visit on the way to another'. I don't think 'take in' is  confined to "go to 'a show or event'". Anyway thanks for your opinion.

It is "take me in"  not "take in {something}".  Different verbs.

It's because 'me' is a personal pronoun: pronouns mus be in the center between the verb and adverb.('take in me' is wrong)
